# justify-content: space-between vs. flex-grow to align content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a top horizontal navigation which I'm using the css flexbox rule to control spacing.

[image]

I would like the the first item in the menu to be aligned to the left, the last item to be aligned to the right and for the spacing in between the rest of the items to be equal.

Is this possible? I thought `justify-content: space-between;` would have achieved this but I can't get it to work.

I put an example of what I'm trying to do on [**jsfiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/xocmob11/3/).  I also put this code below too.

The only other way I can think of doing it is to give a `text-align: center` to each of the `li` elements but for the first and last, which I could give a `text-align: left` and `text-align: right` but this would give too much spacing between the second and second last elements.

```css
.container{
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 1100px;
}
.container ul#nav {
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.container ul#nav li {
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-flex: 2 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 2 1 auto;
  flex: 2 1 auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.container ul#nav li {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Apples</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Oranges</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Pears</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kiwis</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could achieve this by removing the `flex: 2 1 auto;` from `.container ul#nav li` like this:

```css
.container{
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 1100px;
}
.container ul#nav {
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.container ul#nav li {
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-flex: 2 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 2 1 auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.container ul#nav li {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Apples</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Oranges</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Pears</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kiwis</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked.  Do you know why `flex: 2 1 auto;` breaks it?

Comment: It's because you're using the [flex grow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) property to `li` tags and that specifies the flex grow factor of a flex item. `flex: 2 1 auto;` (expanded code: `flex-grow: 2;`, `flex-shrink: 1;` and `flex-basis: auto;`) if you add `flex-grow: 0 !important;` to `li` then it will also works - http://fiddle.jshell.net/yaj8n8ep/

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that if even one element has a **flex-grow > 0**, automatically any value of **justify-content** ceases to have effect, and the positive extra space will be distributed among the items with **flex-grow**.

**In conclution**: "All **flex-items** must have **flex-grow: 0;** in order **justify-content** to work:.

In your specific case the problem is the line: `flex: 2 1 auto;` which automatically set `flex-grow: 2;`

In order to fix it just change the **flex-grow** to **0** with the code line `flex: 0 1 auto;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;

  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">6</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also important to note that `margin` is very important for all of this to work. If you tamper with the margin of elements `justify-content: space-between;` might also not work as flex-box seems to use the margin the justify the content.